# Как преобразовать число в элементе

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="convert">350$</div>
```

Как посредством JS/jQuery преобразовать число в элементе?
Например, `350` умножить на `0.57` и заменить `$` на `руб`.

Таких элементов на странице много, но все они одинакового типа:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="convert">100$</div></li>
    <li><div class="convert">200$</div></li>
    <li><div class="convert">500$</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Насколько универсальное решение вам нужно? Элемент с таким классом у вас только один на странице?

Comment: нет, таких элементов много

Comment: И чем они отличаются? Если вам нужно написать функцию конвертер валют - это будет громоздкое решение

Comment: @Klimenkomud обновил вопрос

Comment: И все нужно умножать именно на 0.57? Если так, то особо ничего сложного

Comment: @Klimenkomud именно так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
var koef=0.57;
$("div.convert").each(function(){
  var price=parseFloat($(this).text().replace("$",""));
  price=parseFloat(price*koef).toFixed(0);
  $(this).html("").html(price+" руб");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><div class="convert">$100.25</div></li>
<li><div class="convert">$200.06</div></li>
<li><div class="convert">$500</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А что если перенести знак $ - перед числом? То есть: <div class="convert">$100</div>. Почему-то отдает результат "nan"

Comment: Обновил код, надо было так изначально сделать, как сейчас))

Comment: в чем смысл `parseFloat(price*koef)`  если и price и koef уже числа?

Comment: `$(this).html("").html(price+" руб");` - можно не делать `.html('')` потому что при вызове `.html(price+" руб")` все равно заменилось бы все содержимое

Comment: а если число не целое? а например 100.25

Comment: 1. Зачем дважды перезаписывать HTML у элементов? 2. Почему запись `.html()`, а не `.text()`? 3. Зачем `parseFloat`? 4. Почему `koef`, а не `coef`? 5. К чему такая экономия на пробелах?

Comment: @Grundy я просто по привычке так делаю))

Comment: @kiLLro, обновил решение, все же просто очень

Comment: @Regent, Ваша комментарий воспринимаю как стеб, если честно

Comment: @DaemonHK весьма напрасно.

Comment: @Regent ок, отвечу 1. Привычка, 2. Привычка, 3. Потому что после умножения дробного числа на целое, получается дробное, 4. Лень было в переводчик лезть (знаю, сам против русских названий в переменных), 5. Привычка, да и Code Style у каждого свой (PSR в гробу видел)

Comment: @DaemonHK 1. Привычка добавлять лишний код, который ещё и снижает производительность (незначительно, но всё же) - это, на мой взгляд, очень странная привычка, от которой стоит избавляться. 3. Зачем с помощью `parseFloat` парсить дробное число в дробное число? В каких случаях это будет лучше чем просто `(price * coef).toFixed(0)`? 5. Стили разные бывают, спору нет, но совсем без пробелов читать сложно, ибо всё сливается. В общем, право ваше, я лишь ожидал что код будет выглядеть [как-то так](https://jsfiddle.net/yqr4tb24/).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66694/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-regent).